# Using excel to query sql server automatically when sheet is opened

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I need an excel sheet along with a batch file such that that: when the batch file runs, the excel sheet opens, runs a query on an SQL database, and saves the contents to a differently named excel file.

I know this is asking a lot, so I apologize for the long request. I know exactly the query that I need to perform and I know how the batch file is supposed to work.

What I am having trouble with is the VBA code inside of excel that runs when the file is opened and performs the query. So, while I know how to run sql queries in SAS and in Micorsoft SQL, I am having a hard time figuring out how to make excel perform these queries automatically in the VBA code. Here's what I have, but it *when I run the code, I get the error "Compile error: user-defined type not defined"

[image]

Comment: Why not set up a connection under the Data tab? You can then choose to have it run automatically upon opening

Comment: Andrew, I can't seem to perform a query this way. It simply drags the table in.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the ADO library to your VBProject.  Tools >> References in the VB editor.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to help

- Create a WorkBook Open Event and place your code there.
- Learn how to open other works books using VBA. The documentation section here on SO has examples
- Learn to write results using Offset property and xlUp command (just in case you need to write results to a log which tends to be the next row/columns

Comment: this is generally more of a comment, but I put it in an "answer" due to readability

Answer (score 0):

I use like this

```
Sub getDAtaFromServer()
    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strOldUDT As String
    Dim strNewUDT As String
    Dim aryTempUDT() As String
    Dim strTempID As String
    Dim i As Integer

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" _
             & "Server=(local);" _
             & "Database=TEST;" _
             & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
             & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;"

    con.Open

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [table] "
    Set rst = cmd.Execute
    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```